# Sanitizing list for Tkinter label

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I'm trying to build a simple name generator as a project, and I've got it to work, but it doesn't output correctly I'm getting outputs like this:

```
{NameA}{NameB}NameC NameD{NameE}
```

While I know for a fact that they are being stored in a list like this:

```
['Name A', 'NameB', 'NameC', 'NameD', 'NameE']
```

Here is the full code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

printout = []

def generate():
for _ in range(var1.get()):
    C = random.randrange(6)

    if C == 0:
        printout.append(random.choice(Prefix))
    elif 1 <= C <= 2:
        printout.append(random.choice(Prefix)+random.choice(Suffix))
    elif 3 <= C <= 5:
        printout.append(random.choice(Prefix)+" "+random.choice(Prefix)+random.choice(Suffix))
var.set(printout)
print(printout)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Simple GUI")
root.geometry("200x200")

var = tk.StringVar()

app = tk.Frame(root)
app.grid()

list1 = [1, 5, 10, 50]
var1 = tk.IntVar(app)
var1.set(1)
drop = tk.OptionMenu(root,var1,*list1)
drop.grid()

label = tk.Label(app, text = "How many results:")
label.grid()

button1 = tk.Button(app, text = "Generate!", command=generate)
button1.grid()


label2= tk.Label(app, textvariable=var)
label2.grid()

with open('D:/My Documents/prefix.txt') as f:
Prefix = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
with open('D:/My Documents/suffix.txt') as r:
Suffix = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in r]

root.mainloop()
```

I can't find anyone have this problem online so I'm not sure what's happening.

Comment: What are the contents of `basroom suffix.txt` and `basroom prefix.txt`?

Comment: Please write a [MCVE] that doesn't require us to have prefix and suffix text files on our D drives.

Comment: What is "santiasing"? Did you mean "sanitizing"?

Comment: @BryanOakley yes, I want it to output as 'NameA NameB NameC' etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curly braces you see in your output are a result of Tkinter trying to print a list as if it were a string. You should explicitly convert your list to a string before passing it to `var.set`.

Comment: Thanks that seemed to have fixed it, even worked out how to create it into a new line at the same time.